# How do I return the number of items found after I do a search?

Tags: java

Please help me to figure out how I can get a count of the result when I do a search against a specific folder?

Also how can I ask the user if they want to perform another search?

```
// Importing utilities
import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;

public class FileListing
{    
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        // Creating a Scanner
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Specifying search location
        File file = new File("D:/Music");

        String[] content = file.list();

        // Searching for a match
        System.out.println("Enter the first few characters of the folder/file to do a lookup");
        String userInput = keyboard.nextLine(); 

        // Adding text to say what the user searched for
        System.out.println("Below you will find the list of folders/files with a partial match to (" + userInput + ").");
        System.out.println();

        // Posting the contents
        for(String folders : content)
        {
            if(folders.toUpperCase().startsWith(userInput.toUpperCase()))
            {
                System.out.println("Name: " + folders);
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to count your matches you can do the following

```
  int i=0;
    // Posting the contents
    for(String folders : content)
    {
        if(folders.toUpperCase().startsWith(userInput.toUpperCase()))
        {
            System.out.println("Name: " + folders);
            i++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Total number of results: " + i);`
```

As for asking the user, consider using a do-while loop in the following format

```
do{
// your code
// ask user and read his answer on a string called userChoice
}while (userChoice.equals('y'))
```

Experiment with our suggestions and you will find the answer easily enough!

Comment: backticks are for inline code like `this`... to make code blocks, indent the code with 4 spaces.  Or select it and hit the {} icon at the top.

Comment: Thank you, i was able to achieve what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a variable

```
int count = 0;
```

right before the for loop, and just increment it if it's a match.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started. I am incrementing the variable `count` each time a match is found. I am also looping forever so it keeps asking the user for more input.

```
// Importing utilities
import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;
public class FileListing
{    
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        // Creating a Scanner
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Specifying search location
        File file = new File("D:/Music");

        String[] content = file.list();

        while(true){

            // Searching for a match
            System.out.println("Enter the first few characters of the folder/file to do a lookup");
            String userInput = keyboard.nextLine(); 

            // Adding text to say what the user searched for
            System.out.println("Below you will find the list of folders/files with a partial match to (" + userInput + ").");
            System.out.println();

            // Posting the contents
            int count=0;
            for(String folders : content)
            {
                if(folders.toUpperCase().startsWith(userInput.toUpperCase()))
                {
                    System.out.println("Name: " + folders);
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this.

Answer (score 0):

Use a while loop and prompt the user to enter a phrase (such as 'exit') if they want to stop. After reading the user input, check the phrase and call a break if it matches the exit phrase.

Use a variable as Robert suggested to count the total number of files found.